# My code is not printing star pattern (+) sign instead it is printing blank space, can you explain why?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

In this code, I am trying to print Plus(+) sign pattern and i don't know what is wrong with my if else condition can you please explain what is wrong with my if else condition and offers a solution ?

let n=5;

let pattn="";

for(i=0;i<n;i++){

for(j=0;j<n;j++){

if(i==n/2||j==n/2){

pattn+="*";

}else

pattn+=" ";

}pattn+=" \n";

}console.log(pattn);

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. It's difficult to read and it can't be copied to a development environment to run.  See [ask]

Comment: Your syntax isn't correct. There's some missing curly braces in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
let n = 5;
let pattn = "";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == 2 || j == 2) {
            pattn += "*";
        } else
            pattn += " ";
    }
    pattn += " \n";
}
console.log(pattn);
```

```js
let n = 5;
let pattn = "";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == 2 || j == 2) {
            pattn += "*";
        } else
            pattn += " ";
    }
    pattn += " \n";
}
console.log(pattn);
```

Comment: thanks it works but i have another question what if we add n numbers instead of 5 then how will you do it ?

Comment: can you please explain what is wrong with my code why it is not producing the same output ?

Comment: change line 6 to this         if (i == Math.floor(n / 2) || j == Math.floor(n / 2))

Comment: cause your divide by 2 is making a floating point number like 2.5 and you have to round it

Comment: oohhh thanks man now i understand